# Postman cannot reach local Jersey REST service

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, postman

While working through a programming book, I implemented a local REST service running in Tomact on port 8081 in the folder webapi (http://localhost:8081/lwchapter1/webapi/user/login). When running a request in Postman I get an error:

```
Could not send request
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081
```

I dont understand, how to debug this and therefore kindly ask for help!

The service is implemented (as far as I understand) like this:

- Postman to test the API
- Tomcat to provide the service
- compiled War File
- maven as a build tool
- java class listening for POST requests in a specific folder

The java project compiles, undeploy/ deploy works and the war file is in the tomcat folder, tomcat is running.

Edit: I found a developer console in Postman giving additional information. Unfortunately this doesn't help either since there is no parameter in the request:

```
Could not find on r. Missing or invalid parameter.
No revision id found for response
```

Comment: Some ideas to try are: a) do you have a firewall or virus scanning software running that is interfering with requests, b) is the service actually running and available to service requests (OS utilities), c) is your service actually running on that port.

Comment: As for debugging, there are tools available that will help you trace the calls. Some of them require some commitment to learn, some of them are easier to learn as they are OS specific utilities.

Comment: @MattVickery thanks a lot for the quick response! :) I work with MacOS, do you have some recommendations? Googeling "trace calls api" doesnt gets me that far... ;)

Comment: I'm sorry the follow-up was not as quick! Try some of the techniques listed here: https://www.lifewire.com/using-netstat-command-on-mac-4176069 Wireshark is also really well worth looking at but you will need to create some filters to reduce the output to look at.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by:

1. checking which ports are open and listened by using
   `netstat -a -n -p tcp | grep 127.0.0.1*`
   in the terminal
2. understanding in which folder the REST service listens by checking the actual java program

Thanks to @MattVickery for your kind help, I really appreciated it!

Comment: Thank you for expressing appreciation, I’m glad to have helped.